# How to solve this math Function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How can I solve this math Funcion with Haskell? 
Can anyone help me?

[Rekursive math Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2let6.png)

```
myFunc n m = myFuncRec n m if m <= n then 1
                       else myFuncRec n(m - 1):[]
```

Do I need two recursion? because for this problem in java needs two or three loops.

Comment: Hint: use `sum`.

Answer (score 7):

I would normally give a hint instead of a full solution, but since this question is mostly about syntax, and the translation is very close, almost literal, I'll just give it to you in full.

[image: math thing]

```
p n m 
    | m <= n    = 1
    | otherwise = sum [ p n (m - i) | i <- [1..n] ]
```

The bars distinguishing the different cases by conditions are called *guards*, and the bracket structure in the last line is known as a *list comprehension*.

Comment: I'm laughing the answer is really small. but despite difficult for newbie. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Almost equally literal, but in a different sense, is `p n m = if m <= n then 1 else sum [...]`.

Answer (score 4):

luqui's answer gives the natural, straightforward translation of the math definition into Haskell code. As a specification, it is perfect: beautiful and obviously correct. As a teaching tool, it is perfect: easy to read, easy to understand, and no advanced features used. But as an *algorithm* it is a little unfortunate: the existence of many recursive calls that each do recomputation makes it very slow for large inputs. So in this answer I will give a taste of what a solution not intended for simplicity might look like.

One observation of interest is that `P(2,-)` is the Fibonacci sequence, which has a well-known, beautiful, and efficient definition as an infinite list in Haskell:

```
fibs = 1:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

This recursively-defined list uses itself as a memoization table. One might ask whether there is a clean generalization of this trick to P with other first arguments than 2; the answer is yes. The basic idea is this: since `transpose` is the natural extension of `zip` to arbitrary arity, and `sum` is the natural extension of `(+)` to arbitrary arity, we can write:

```
import Data.List

transposeWith :: ([a] -> b) -> [[a]] -> [b]
transposeWith f xss = map f (transpose xss)

genFib :: Int -> [Integer]
genFib n = result where
    result = replicate n 1 ++ transposeWith sum [drop i result | i <- [0..n-1]]
```

This gives us an efficient way to compute `P(n,-)` for any `n`, using a list for memoization. If we wish to memoize even the `n` dimension, we can write:

```
p :: [[Integer]]
p = map genFib [1..]
```

How much faster is it? On my machine, computing `P(100, 130)` takes luqui's solution more than ten minutes (and appears to roughly double in time each time you add one to `m`), while my solution responds in under a second for even such a large input as `P(100, 10000)`.